# Getting an error while trying to create conda env from .yml file

Tags: conda

I have created an enviornment file env.yml from a conda environment available on my machine, i tried to create a new envionment using the .yml file
but the system keep giving me the following error

```
(base) Aymans-MacBook-Air:heart-disease-project aymaneltouny$ conda create --prefix ./env -f env.yml
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - env.yml

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I checked the channels in them yml file and I made sure that the conde-forge is included in the channel list.
I checked the python version it is python 3.8.5, while it is in the nev.yml 3.8.12, I am not sure if this the problem and if so how I can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-f` flag is not for file, but is a deprecated flag for `--force`.  The `conda env` command set supports `-f`, and if you have a **YAML** file, you should use:

```
conda env create -f env.yml -p ./env
```

If your file is a *spec* file, then you can use the standard `conda create` command set:

```
conda create --file env.spec -p ./env
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is now working using "conda env create -f env.yml -p ./env"